# Check if randomized number is in an array, if true then randomize again?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a battleship game, and I'm trying to randomize the computer's ships. However, it sometimes randomizes the same location more than once, thus creating less than 8 ships in some rounds. I tried to fix this using indexOf but I can't seem to get it to work no matter how I change the code. If the randomized number is in the array shipLocations then I want to reroll the number again until it's a number that doesn't match any number in the array. Any ideas?

```
var shipLocations = [];

function randShips() {

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

        var randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64 + 1);

    if (shipLocations.indexOf(randomize) == true) {
        var randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64 + 1);
    }

    else {
        shipLocations.push(randomize);    
    }

    } //end of i loop

} //end of randShips()

randShips();
console.log(shipLocations);
```

**EDIT:** So after trying out a few of the answers, this seems to be working the way it should be after testing about 100 times.

```
var shipLocations = [];

function randShips() {

while (shipLocations.length < 8) {

    var randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64 + 1);

    while (shipLocations.indexOf(randomize) > -1) {
        randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64 + 1);
    }

    shipLocations.push(randomize);
}
}

randShips();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var shipLocations = [];

function randShips() {

    while ( shipLocations.length < 8 ) {
        var randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64 + 1);
        while ( shipLocations.indexOf(randomize) >= 0 ) {
            randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64 + 1);            
        }
        shipLocations.push(randomize);
    }

} //end of randShips()

randShips();
console.log(shipLocations);
```

Comment: So if the generated random number is in the array at index `0`, that's ok to add it again? ;)

Comment: ye I just noticed that bug when testing, how to fix? set to -1?

Comment: powerMock changed his answer to say `>= 0` so if the `indexOf()` returns a value equal to `0` a new number is generated. Or you could use the snippet from my answer in place of your `if` part.

Comment: I missed `=`. Now it seems to be ok. :) Thank @funkwurm for observation. @Chrillewoodz: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wk1prxhw/1/

Comment: Had to tweak your answer a little but it works once u add either -1 or >= 0 instead of > 0

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` doesn't return boolean value, it returns the index (int) of the matched element.

So the code should be

```
if (~shipLocations.indexOf(randomize)) {
    var randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64 + 1);
}
```

You could use this function to get a true unique number that for the array.

```
function uniqueRandom( arr) {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64 + 1);
    if (~arr.indexOf(num)) {
        uniqueRandom(arr);
    } else {
        return num;
    }
}
```

Btw, the logic you had written has a problem. If you found a duplicate number, you just randomize it again, without pushing it into the array. so using a `while` or a recursive function should do the job quite well.

Comment: 1. What does the ~ do?
2. When I tried the code, I got only 6 numbers a few times. It's like it doesn't randomize a new number, just skips it?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Binary negation. For clarity, I'd have used `shipLocations.indexOf(randomize) >= 0` instead.

Comment: It is Bitwise NOT operator, it would return a falsely value if the indexOf returns `-1` (all other values greater than zero signifies that the value is found)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want 8 unique values, it's quite possible that 2 numbers created in a row are both in the array already. So I think you'll want to do a `while`:

```
while (shipLocations.indexOf(randomize) != -1) {
    randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64 + 1);
}
```

The `var` part shouldn't be there, that is only necessary for the first instance of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript false conditions are returned with a value of **-1**.

Hence, change the **if-else** condition to :

```
if (shipLocations.indexOf(randomize) != -1) { //true condition equivalent
    var randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64 + 1);
}

else {
    shipLocations.push(randomize);    
}
```

Comment: "false conditions are returned with a value of -1". That's not really true. `indexOf()` happens to give -1 when it cannot find the index, because -1 is distinctly different from 0 (a valid index, namely the first one) and `0 == false` so that would be confusing.